# Why I'm not able to view the source of any js file in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web-developer-toolbar

This one works:

```
view-source:http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js
```

This one does not:

```
view-source:http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
```

The network status is "canceled". Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
P3P: policyref="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DEV PSA PSD IVA IVD OTP OUR OTR IND OTC"
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
ETag: 18135184975683587730
Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 10:00:44 GMT
Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2013 11:00:44 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: cafe
Content-Length: 6489
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Age: 2014
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
```

Without "view-source" I'm able to download the file and view the source but I want to know why this happens.

A strange thing in addition is, that it is not possible to open the web delevoper tools after opening this view-source url. If you do, the tools are completely blank:
[image: web developer tools missing]

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here: it has to do with the **Content-Disposition** setting in the Response Header.

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519.